# ASP.Net FileUpload: Rename file name before saving if already exists

Tags: c#, file-upload, upload

I need change file name when users upload from file **upload control**.

If file name be duplicate it add count at file name but here it doesn't  work.

I mean when I upload file i.e. **00076007-2013.pdf** it saves in the  host with this name **00076007-2013(0).pdf**

But when again I want upload **00076007-2013.pdf** in host it overwrite last (**00076007-2013(0).pdf**).

But I want if there was **00076007-2013.pdf** file it saves with this name  **00076007-2013(1).pdf** in host.

[image]

How I can solve this problem.

My code below.

```
    int count = 0;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string FileExstention = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/public/2Version/sk_PDF/"));


    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if (FileExstention == ".pdf")
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/public/2Version/sk_PDF/") + fileName.ToString()))
                {
                    foreach (string s in files)
                    {
                        string filename = string.Empty;
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(s).Substring(0, Path.GetFileName(s).LastIndexOf("."));

                        if (filename.Contains("("))
                        {
                            filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf("("));
                        }

                        if (filename == fileName.ToString().Trim())
                        {
                            count++;
                        }

                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/public/2Version/sk_PDF/") + filename.ToString() + "(" + count.ToString() + ")" + FileExstention);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/public/2Version/sk_PDF/") + fileName.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit #01**
This is the output.

I have upload the **00076007-2013.pdf** file for three times.

The first time OK,  **00076007-2013.pdf**.

The second time OK, **00076007-2013(0).pdf**.

The last time he was saved **00076007-2013(0).pdf** and not **00076007-2013(1).pdf**

[image]

Comment: Check the file exists server side before saving?

Comment: Are you sure you want to add condition before increment 'count' variable? it seems that you want always to increment it when theres already a file with that same name , have you debugged it and that condition matches true?

Comment: @BugFinder Please see **Edit #01** in my first question.

Comment: @TiagoSilva Please see **Edit #01** in my first question.

Comment: your edit is unrelated  with my comment, debug it and check if the count variable actually gets incremented

Comment: Your filename.. gets chunked down to 00076007-2013 of which there are 0.. because you at least want the .pdf on the end, so it always remains at 0 however many times you save it As @TiagoSilva says, a simple debug would show this

Answer (score 0):

Please change this part :

```
if (filename.Contains("("))
{
    filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf("("));
}
```

With :

```
if (filename.Contains("("))
{
    filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf("("));
    count++;
}
```

I hope I was helpful.